# Prevent socket from automatically closing connection

Tags: c#, client-server

so I am trying to learn basic network communication in C#, I have this code on the client side:

```
    static void Connect(String server, String message)
    {
        try
        {

            Int32 port = 13000;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            data = new Byte[256];
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Connect("127.0.0.1", "something");
    }}
```

It works fine, however what I was trying to do for last few hours is decouple socket opening and holding connection from sending and receiving messages. What i want to do is to have one independent function that I will call and it connects to the server through socket this connection should then stay open and allow me to send request and receive responses by calling other functions/methods, until I  tell it to close.

However what happens now if i try to basically split this code into two functions (connect and send/receive), while making socket variable global, is that the connect works fine, but when i try to call the  send/receive function the socket is disconnected/closed. (Note that I am not calling socket.Close()). I am sure that there is some fundamental problem that I missed, but cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Edit: This is my idea of how to do it:

```
static TcpClient client;
    static void Connect(String server)
    {
        try
        {

            Int32 port = 13000;
            client = new TcpClient(server, port);

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }


    }
    static string sendRec(string message)
    {
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        data = new Byte[256];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
        return responseData;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Connect("127.0.0.1");
        string a = sendRec("test");
    }
```

But it does not work. It throws: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
InnerEx:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
But I cant figure out which object is the issue, I assume its the socket.

Comment: Are you calling client.Close();  near the end of Connect Method? In global code perspective - you need to keep the socket open until all communication is done. So do not close the client.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I am not, I have upsated the question to show my attempt. Thanks.

Comment: If its not just a Typo - your Connect method is missing client.Connect() - i.e. your socket isnt open yet.

Comment: @ Well I thought that initializing a new TcpClient with server and port agruments takes care of that. And the fact that it is missing in the original code too and it works and communicates with the server would support this. Anyway even if I add client.Connect(server,port); it changes nothing.